# Images are squishing vertically on iphone 8 (chrome & safari)

Tags: html, css

I'm learning html and css and decided to redo my wordpress site in html/css (site is saigonpads.com).

I'm close to the finish line, but the images in my "Photos of Our Expat Pads" section at http://www.saigonpads.com/test/saigonpads.html (my html/css/javascript version of the site) are not resizing with their aspect ratio. They are squished vertically. The site works fine with chrome and IE on my desktop, tablets, and mobile phone (samsung).

Here is a screenshot of the issue: https://prnt.sc/obw5tp

Here's how I'd like it to look: https://prnt.sc/obw6gw

Here is the relevant css and html pertaining to the issue.

```css
        img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        #photo-group {
            padding-top: 20px;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .room-photos {
            border: 0px solid;
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 10px;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            display: flex;
        }
        .section {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 90%;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
```

```html
        <div class="section" id="room-photos">
            <h3>PHOTOS OF OUR EXPAT PADS</h3>
            <hr>
            <div id="photo-group">
                <img class="room-photos" src="room-photo-1.jpg">
                <img class="room-photos" src="room-photo-2.jpg">
                <img class="room-photos" src="room-photo-3.jpg">
                <img class="room-photos" src="room-photo-4.jpg">
                <img class="room-photos" src="room-photo-5.jpg">
                <img class="room-photos" src="room-photo-6.jpg">
                <img class="room-photos" src="room-photo-7.jpg">
                <img class="room-photos" src="room-photo-8.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: beacause your img are son of photo-group. photo-group is a flex-element so, by default it has align-items:stretch. so your img are stretched. try to set to #photo-group{align-items:flex-start for example.

Comment: Yes, this is it! You are a hero, sir!